# VT-x is not working after enabling from bios. Disabling it shows VT-x available from intel identifications

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, intel, virtualization, bios

I have read almost all the post to make VT-x working. I tried to disable Hyper-V, enable Virtual Machine features etc.

I found one weird thing. If in DISABLE VT-x from bios: i cupid, intel identification app and securable is saying I have VT-x. (See photo below):

[When VT-x is DISABLE from bios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhvoY.png)

However, If I turn ON/ENABLE Intel Virtualization from bios all of them say negative thing about having VT-x.
[When VT-x is Enabled from bios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSDgM.png)

Isn't it just opposite what it should be? Anybody has any idea how to solve this? I am trying to install virtualbox to install MacOS in my Windows Laptop.

Comment: When you enable it, maybe the OS you boot chooses to use it to virtualize itself.  Then programs running under that OS detect VT-X as unavailable inside the virtual guest?  Some Q&As about HAXM talk about Windows settings to let a Windows program *use* VT-x.  Apparently it can be non-trivial to get Windows to keep its hands off of virtualization capabilities, leaving them available for use.  (and BTW, I think you mean `cpuid`, not cupid.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like some application or some service of my Windows is using VT-x. I could not find which one is that unfortunately. If I could some how find that application or service, I could have use virtualbox. Unfortunately, I guess there is no way to find that out :(   ..   
Notes: Yes you are right I meant cpuid :D